# Is there a grid shell extension for gnome? like compizconfig

Tags: resize, gnome-shell-extension

I want to be able minimize windows with hotkeys to top-left,top-right,bottom-left,bottom-right. I had this with unity but I can't find this on gnome. I need this to work with hotkeys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it in Ubuntu Software. "[Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)" GNOME shell extension. sweet.

Answer (score 0):

For those new to Gnome and its extensions, full installation instructions for "Put Windows" are here: [How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04/1089033#1089033).

Answer (score 0):

[Awesome Tiles](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4702/awesome-tiles/) works well.

[Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) doesn´t work with Ubuntu 22.04/Gnome 42 as of the date of this answer.