# GNOME extension error on browser unable to connect

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am trying to get snap to corner on Ubuntu.

I am following the instructions below trying to get GNOME extension working on a browser. I am up to step 2 and have tried Chrome and Firefox, with both giving me a extensions.gnome.org refused to connect or unable to connect error.

[How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04)

How can I install GNOME extensions through the browser?.

Comment: Sounds like a temporary issue with the extensions.gnome.org website. Please try again later and see.

Comment: @pomsky yes it does look like it from the [https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/extensions.gnome.org]( is it down) , do you know when its going to be online? or do you know of any other way to get the snap to corner feature?

Comment: No idea when it'll be back, hopefully pretty soon! There are other ways to install GNOME extensions, check *all* the answers here: Possible duplicate of [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

Comment: I have noticed that extensions that I have installed have not been working for the last two hours. Is the installed extensions dependent on extensions.gnome.org to be available? So they will not run unless extensions.gnome.org server is up and running? That seems strange, then there should be some kind of a backup solution in case, so the user's installed extensions can still run if the server is down.