# Ubuntu numpad shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, numpad

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and I want to create shortcuts like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Num_7</kbd> to move the active window to top-left corner, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Num_4</kbd> to move the active window to left, etc, for all 9 numpad numbers.

How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop environment does not support quarter tiling (the kind of tiling that you want).

There are some GNOME Shell extensions that offer more advanced tiling options, but I am not sure if they can do exactly what you want. The most popular are:

- [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)
- [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)
- [WinTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/)

To install and try them, you have to first install Tweaks and `chrome-gnome-shell` by running:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then click the extensions' links above, flip the switch to *ON* and click *Install* in the popup dialog.

I have also found this [Python script](https://github.com/ifischer/window-tiler) from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208274/move-window-to-screen-corners-using-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu-18-04). I haven't tried it yet, but looks like it could work. I will update my answer when I try this.

You could also try another Ubuntu version, like Xubuntu, Kubuntu or Ubuntu-MATE, which all offer options to do what you want (Xubuntu has the shortcuts you need enabled by default; I am not sure about the other environments).

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in-functions with `wm` keybindings..

to see what are those functions either use `gsettings` command or use dconf-editor tool (to install `dconf-editor` run `sudo apt install dconf-editor`)

gsettings command:

`gsettings list-recursively | grep wm.keybindings | grep move-to`

```
pratap@pratap:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep wm.keybindings | grep move-to
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-8 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-9 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-left ['<Super>KP_4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-5 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-6 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-10 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-11 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-12 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w ['<Super>KP_4']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw ['<super>KP_7']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-down ['<Super><Shift>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-right ['<Super><Shift>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-last ['<Super><Shift>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-monitor-up ['<Super><Shift>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-1 ['<Super><Shift>Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-2 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-3 @as []
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-4 @as []
pratap@pratap:~$
```

you can use this syntax `['<Super>KP_4']` to assign the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>KP_4</kbd>

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w "['<Super>KP_4']"
```

Or use the simple GUI way with dconf-editor

[image]