# GNOME Shell Extension Put Windows stopped working

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Presumably after an update to GNOME Shell, '*Put Windows*' extension stopped working.

This was only discovered after trying to put a window into a corner (upper leftmost) of the screen using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (numeric keypad). The GNOME Shell Extension website - Installed extensions showed ERROR in the place where the extension is turned ON or OFF.

How can I fix this issue?

---

<sub>This was reported on the GNOME website with a support ticket and has been resolved.</sub>

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for the enhancements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reporting the problem I got the following response from Gnome which has SOLVED the issue:

"Version 27 is now inactive and v26 is the most current version. Please check, that you are using v26"

So, I restarted gnome with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and then selected 3.26 as the Extension version to reinstall it.

[image]

The extension now works again as it should.

Comment: Thank you! My Put Windows just quit working on Ubuntu 18.04 (I had configured it [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089033/327339) 8 months ago), I think because it had an update it wanted me to install--which I did, and your `Alt` + `F2` + `r` trick to restart Gnome worked perfectly, after **not even a computer restart had worked**! Thank you.