# How to get quarter-window snapping for Ubunt18.04 Metacity

Tags: gnome, window, metacity

My Ubuntu 18.04.04 cannot install numerous applications that are designed to allow quarter-window snapping.

I'm running Gnome 3.28.2

I'm running Metacity on GNOME Flashback I think.  My shell version is `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` This is the best GNOME window manager IMHO.

1. [How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04)

This shows how to install "Put Windows" but it doesn't fit my shell version.  I clicked on the GitHub page, but the instructions do not show how to install for shell version 4.

I successfully installed `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions chrome-gnome-shell`

It appears that "Put Windows" doesn't work for Metacity.
Furthermore, it appears to me that gnome-shell-extensions doesn't work for Metacity.

I've also tried install `ShellTile` & `gTile` at the command line, but this also failed.

How can I get the quarter-window capability with Metacity?

Comment: Metacity does not support that. Also `gnome-shell` extensions does not work in GNOME Flashback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [X-Tile](https://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/) for custom window tiling.

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.giuspen.com/software/x-tile_3.3-0_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./x-tile_3.3-0_all.deb
```

and you will get something like:

[image: GNOME Metacity with X-Tile]

Or better - install MATE desktop to use its preinstalled tiling features:

[image: MATE corner tiling]